# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' when using clustering + classification models together

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, k-means

I created a clustering model to try and find different groups of customers based on annual income and spending score using the KMeans algorithm from Scikit-Learn. Using the cluster value that it returned for each customer, I tried to create a classification model using Support Vector Classification from sklearn.svm. When I tried to fit the new model onto the dataset, however, I got an error message:

```
File "/Users/user/Documents/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 4 - Clustering/Section 24 - K-Means Clustering/cluster_and_prediction.py", line 28, in <module>
    classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py", line 149, in fit
    y = self._validate_targets(y)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py", line 525, in _validate_targets
    check_classification_targets(y)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 169, in check_classification_targets
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

My code is as follows

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# Using relevant columns from dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Mall_Customers.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, 3:5].values

# Creating model with ideal amount of clusters
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
kmeans.fit(x)

predictions = kmeans.predict(x)

# Creating numpy array for feature scaling
predictions = np.array(predictions, dtype=int)
predictions = predictions[:, None]

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_x = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
x = sc_x.fit_transform(x)
predictions = sc_y.fit_transform(predictions)

# Splitting dataset into training and test sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, predictions, test_size=.25)

# Creating Support Vector Classification model
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier = SVC(kernel='rbf')
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

[Elbow Model Used for Clustering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO0K1.png)

[Clustering Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQSlS.png)

[.zip file with the dataset(the dataset is called 'Mall_Customers.csv'](https://sds-platform-private.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/P14-K-Means.zip)

How can I fix this?

Comment: *Where exactly* does the error pop up? Please update your post to include the full error trace (as text, not image).

Comment: Rather - it looks like you're trying to predict continuous data with the SVC model, which only accepts categorical data. [class labels in classification, real numbers in regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit)

Comment: The clustering model that I created divides the clients into 5 different groups, and the value of the group becomes the y-variable for the classification model(as seen in the "Clustering Visualization" graph. Wouldn't that count as categorical data? (sorry beginner machine learning programmer here) Also, could it be that svm is a binary classifier?

Comment: Code that comes *after* the error should not be included here (it is never executed, hence irrelevant); the same holds true for plots etc which are *irrelevant to the issue* - all these just create unnecessary clutter (edited out). Now, please post a sample of your `y_train` and `kmeans.predict(x)`.

Comment: ... and cleaning the code from the clutter helped me resolve the issue (see answer below)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry about the unnecessary clutter, it was my first time posting on stackoverflow and I wanted to make sure I gave all the information I had.

Comment: No problem, just keep it in mind for the future - posting all our code as-is is never the correct approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to address this as a classification problem with 5 classes, you should *not* use a scaler for your labels; this converts them to continuous variables fed in a classification model, hence the error.

Also, irrelevant to the issue, but the correct methodology is to fit your scaler on your training data only, and then use this fitted scaler to transform your test data.

So, here are the necessary changes (after you have finished with setting your `predictions` variable):

```
# initial (unscaled) x used here:
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, predictions, test_size=.25)
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train_scaled = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_scaled = sc.transform(x_test)

classifier = SVC(kernel='rbf')
classifier.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train) # no scaling for predictions or y_train
```

Also irrelevant to the issue, but you should scale your `x` data *before* using k-means, i.e. you should actually scale your `x` first and then perform your clustering (leaving it as an exercise, as it has nothing to do with the error).